# Не знаю, как оптимизировать открытие диалогового окна Swing JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

В моей программе использую для выбора файла JFileChooser.
Всё прекрасно работает, да вот только после нажатия на кнопку(при первом нажатии, при последующих всё нормально) приходится ждать секунд 5, пока он подумает и откроет.

Очень хотелось бы узнать, как мне оптимизировать это, может быть как-то подгружать Swing при открытии самого приложения, только я не знаю как.

Также, когда оно открывается, окно оказывается позади приложения, я как понял это можно решить, указав ей родителя, но в качестве родителя он требует awt компонент, когда я использую javaFX.

Вот небольшой фрагмент открытия JFileChooser:

```
 @FXML
    void chooseImage(ActionEvent event){
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int operation = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
}
```

Comment: как оказалось, в linux он у меня вообще не открывается

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил. А что за мета сайт?

Comment: а зачем вы смешали в кучу swing и javafx? это разные технологии. у javafx есть свой FileChooser